# MPAndroidChart - How add put and show legends in a PieChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I´m read various tutoriais but most of then show the same example. The legend array is put in a constructor of:

`new PieData(legendValues, IPieDataSet dataSet)`

But PieData doesn't have this constructor.

Does have anyone a sample code for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using the latest `3.0.0-beta1` version of the library. For that version a lot of (breaking) changes were made to support `float` x-values.

Specifically, the [`PieData`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.0-beta1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/PieData.html) constructor has changed and now only accepts an `IPieDataSet`. The labels are now set with the [`PieEntry`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.0-beta1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/PieEntry.html) which has a `PieEntry(float value, String label)` constructor. Here's a small example illustrating how you set labels in the latest version of the library:

```
ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new PieEntry(25, "Android 5.0"));
entries.add(new PieEntry(25, "Android 5.1"));
entries.add(new PieEntry(25, "Android 6.0"));
PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "Android versions");
PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
```